# Converting UIImage to Data throws unsupported file format

Tags: swift

I'm using the image picker to select a photo from photo library or to take a camera and in my `imagePickerController` function, I get the UIImage and try to convert it to an Image Data like this

```
let uiImage = info.[UIImagePickerController.Infokey.originalImage] as! UIImage
let imageData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)! // this line throws error
```

And I keep getting this error

> findWriterForTypeAndAlternateType:119: unsupported file format 'public.heic'

And also when I try to update my imageview like this `Image(uiImage)` the view gets updated but I don't know why I'm getting that error.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. What if you use PHPickerViewController instead of the outmoded UIImagePickerController?

Comment: Okay... I'm still new to Swift. So I don't know much about PHPickerViewController

Comment: My problem is that I can't reproduce the issue even using UIImagePickerController. — Also please show your real code. The code you have shown wouldn't compile, so it must be something you typed directly into the question. Don't do that; always copy and paste real code.

Answer (score -1):

Okay... I've got it working. I don't know for what reason, but I changed my`imageData` to this:

```
let imageData = Data((uiImage.pngData())!)
```